# App Won't Start On Bootup When Using Cron

Tags: cron

I have a ts3.desktop file in my /usr/share/applications folder that I want to run on system boot. The procedure I used to try and get this working is below.

```
crontab -e
```

Then in the editor (it opens nano), I typed the following line at the bottom of file. I also made the necessary carriage return after this line.

```
@reboot gtk-launch ts3 /usr/share/applications
```

Then I pressed ctrl+o to save it.

After I put these commands in, I did the following command to help you guys with troubleshooting this issue, see below.

```
$ crontab -l
no crontab for server
$ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep
root         532      1   0 21:35 ?                 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

I'm not sure why it says no crontab for [user], maybe it will help you guys troubleshoot this issue with me. The second line apparently shows that cron is actually running.

After I reboot the file doesn't execute, i.e. the application doesn't start. I don't really know what to do, please advise.

FYI, the ts3.desktop file contents is below, and it has rwx permissions for everyone (and executes properly when the file is double clicked).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Applications
Exec=/usr/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
Icon=/usr/share/icons/ts3/ts3.jpg
Terminal=true
Name=Ts3
```

Answer (score -1):

cron jobs do not have access to the gui ( if there even is one ).  If you want to run a gui app each time you log in to the gui, then use the startup applications tool.

Comment: This is not a GUI app...

Comment: @johnsmith, `gtk-launch` sure is.

Comment: I don't know what it means, I just google the commands because nobody is going to teach me. I promise you, it doesn't open a gui. Even if I  put a reference to the .sh script instead of the gtk- bla bla command, it doesn't work

Comment: @johnsmith, whether it opens a window itself or not is irrelevant; the command makes use of / requires a working GTK/X11/GUI session to operate.  The second line of the man page description reads "The application is started with proper startup notification on a default display, unless specified otherwise".  Here *display* refers to an X11 session identified by the DISPLAY environment variable, which cron jobs do not have, nor is there any guarantee that there even is an X11 server running on the system.